# Facebook PHP web app doesn't work when accessed from account other than app administrator

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have a very simple PHP app that retrieves a users & friends RSVPd events using FQL. It is using the latest PHP SKD. The code works perfectly when I am logged in and authenticated as the account that created the app, but it fails with 'unknown error' if I am logged in and authenticated as anyone else.

Here is the login portion of my code

```
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = $validId;
$config['secret'] = $validSecret;

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$uid = $facebook->getUser();

    // get the url where to redirect the user
$location = "". $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_events, friends_events'));

// check if we have valid user
if ($uid) {
    try {
        $fb_user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');   

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $fb_user_id = NULL;
        // seems we don't have enough permissions
        print '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> top.location.href="'. $location .'"; </script>';

        // kill the code so nothing else will happen before user gives us permissions
        die();
    }

} else {
    // seems our user hasn't logged in

    print '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> top.location.href="'. $location .'"; </script>';

    // kill the code so nothing else will happen before user gives us permissions
    die();
}

print "Authenticated ". $fb_user_profile['name']." <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a><br>";
```

Here is the FQL portion of my code

```
$param  =   array(
  'method'    => 'fql.query',
  'query'     => $validFqlQuery,
  'callback'  => '',
  'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken()
 );

echo "<br>Working...";

 $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param); 

print_r($fqlResult);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your App needs to be reviewed by Facebook before it goes Live for
>   other users to Login.

You do not need to go through `Login Review` if your app requests these three basic permissions:

- public_profile
- user_friends
- email

To ask your app's users for any other permissions, you will need to submit for review.

However, in order to help you craft your Facebook Login experience, your *app's* *developers* will be able to see, and grant, any permission without requiring review by Facebook.

> Note: People who are listed in your app's Roles tab will have access
>   to extended permissions without going through review (e.g.
>   publish_actions or manage_pages). For example, if you use the Facebook
>   Plugin for Wordpress to publish your blog posts to your Facebook Page
>   or Profile, you do not need to submit for review so long as all your
>   publishers are listed in your app's Roles tab.